# How did messages in art, entertainment, etc. influence perception of Canada?

Tags: cultural-history, canada, victorian

How did messages in art, entertainment, and official publications shape the English Canadian view of Canada's the world at the time of the Victorian era?

So far how I understand it, is that the covers of much art (especially the painting of Britannia in the middle, surrounded by various races across the world, showing White Englishmen's superiority in the world in status, entertainment, taste in culture, art, economy, technology, etc.) helped solidify this message that Canada, being a British colony, was the pinnacle of technology, power, status, etc.

Are there any more sources, or information that prove this statement? I'm researching information for an essay, and would really appreciate some more info. I'm slightly lacking a bit.

Comment: I misread "massages" and I was totally WTF?!?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a source request.

Comment: Very difficult to prove "influence" in the general case; easy to offer an opinion, but difficult to demonstrate.